# Writing GUI applications on Mac OS X with c++

Tags: c++, macos, user-interface

I need to display some Gui to the user with c++ on Mac OS X. I know that for using Cocoa I need to use Obj-c++, but I am wondering if there is a way to show very simple Gui to the user only using c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind your app being restricted to 32-bit-mode only (and you enjoy pain ;^)) you can always use MacOS/X's old [Carbon APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_%28API%29).   (They are C APIs but as such are easily callable from a C++ app)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the Gtk+ or Qt libraries, both of which I believe have support for OS X

Here are links to both of them:
Qt: http://qt.nokia.com/products/
Gtk+: http://www.gtk.org/

Comment: I know how to do it with qt:) It provides cocoa interface but the thing i need is to just show some graphics without using any external libraries, I am sure that this is possible. If it isn't, i'll need to use assembly language because my program needs to be really small:)

Comment: Assembly isn't going to help you here; if you instantiate Cocoa objects, you're going to get the same ObjC runtime, whether you're doing it in ObjC, C, or assembly.