# Whats a good program for making C++ GUI for osx

Tags: c++, c, macos, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing GUI applicatins on Mac OS X with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055249/writing-gui-applicatins-on-mac-os-x-with-c)

I am looking for an easy to use program/framework for making c++ GUI on a mac.

Comment: You mean the official tool (Interface Builder) and official framework (Cocoa) isn't good enough?

Comment: I am sorry I should have mentioned that I am looking for an alternative to it.

Comment: Can you describe why you need an alternative? Most other tools, like Qt or Java's various interface creators, create apps that look terrible on the Mac because they don't use the native widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt is a very popular C++ GUI framework that targets Mac (and Windows and Linux and mobile)

http://qt.nokia.com/

Answer (score 0):

you might give JUCE a try:

http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php